# factory pattern using spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, factory-method

How can I choose a service implementation depending on a request parameter on SpringBoot? I can do this by manually instantiating the service, but that's not making use of the Spring Injection feature. 
I can also Autowire the two services separately but I'm thinking that if I have more implementations that would pollute the class.

Here's a crude example:

```
@RestController
class RestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    PizzaService pizzaService;

    public void bakePizza(@RequestParam("type") String type,@RequestParam("extra") String extra) {

        if (type.equals("cheese")) {
            //set pizzaService Cheese Implementation
            pizzaService = new CheezePizza();
        } else {
            //set PizzaService vegetable Impleentation;
            pizzaService = new VegetablePizza();
        }
        pizzaService.prepareIngredients(extra);
        pizzaService.bakePizza();
    }

}

public abstract class PizzaService {

    String ingredients;

    public abstract void prepareIngredients(String exraIngredient);

    public void bakePizza() {
        System.out.println("baking pizza with " + ingredients);
    }
}

class CheezePizza extends PizzaService {

    @Override
    public void prepareIngredients(String exraIngredient) {
        ingredients = "Cheese " + exraIngredient;
    }
}

class VegetablePizza extends PizzaService {
    @Override
    public void prepareIngredients(String exraIngredient) {
        ingredients = "Vegetable " + exraIngredient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could autowire list of beans of same type. So let's say you add `getType()` to your `PizzaService` and register every type as spring bean.

```
public abstract class PizzaService {
    abstract String getType();
}

@Component
class CheezePizza extends PizzaService {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "cheese";
    }
}

@Component
class VegetablePizza extends PizzaService {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "vegetable";
    }
}


@RestController
class RestControllerTest {

    private final Map<String, PizzaService> pizzaServices;

    public RestControllerTest(List<PizzaService> services) {
        pizzaServices = services.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(PizzaService::getType, Function.identity()));
    }

    public void bakePizza(@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("extra") String extra) {
        PizzaService pizzaService = pizzaServices.get(type); // remember of handling missing type
        pizzaService.prepareIngredients(extra);
        pizzaService.bakePizza();
    }

}
```

Another way is to use name your beans by convention i.e. `cheesePizza`, `vegetablePizza` and then use `ApplicationContext#getBean(type + "Pizza")` but I like first approach better, because it's less magical.